# Plot a matrix, values as colors

Tags: matlab, matrix, plot

I have random matrix with arbitrary dimensions and I want to assign a color for each value (randomly or not) and plot the matrix with numbers like,

[image]

So far I've done this,

```
m = 12;
n = 8;
A = randi(5,[m n]);
Arot = flipud(A);
pcolor(Arot);figure(gcf);
for i = 1 : n -1
    for j = 1 : m -1
        text(i + .5 , j + .5 ,num2str(Arot(j,i)),'FontSize',18);
    end
end
```

which gives me this,

[image]

for

```
 A =

 4     4     4     1     2     1     4     2
 5     2     2     3     2     1     1     2
 1     2     1     4     1     2     5     5
 1     3     5     3     1     4     1     3
 3     4     4     4     3     3     3     4
 2     5     2     2     1     1     2     4
 1     3     1     3     5     5     2     4
 5     1     2     4     1     4     1     2
 2     4     5     5     1     3     5     2
 4     2     2     3     4     3     3     4
 3     5     3     2     4     3     3     1
 1     4     5     3     2     4     3     5
```

but as you can see I've lost first row and last column of `A`.

Actually the problem starts bu using `pcolor`, which gives an `(m-1)x(n-1)` plot for `mxn` input.

Any suggestions?

Thanks,

Comment: @AnonSubmitter85, yes, but if I don't use them the lost row and column will be written out side of the plot.

Comment: Yeah, I noticed that when I ran the code. If you look at the help section, you'll see that "In the default shading mode, 'faceted', each cell has a constant color and the last row and column of C are not used."

Comment: @AnonSubmitter85, That was interesting!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just padded the matrix prior to `pcolor` and I think it's the effect you wanted. The reason it works comes from the help doc for `pcolor`, which states that

> In the default shading mode, 'faceted', each cell has a constant color
>   and the last row and column of C are not used.

```
m = 12;
n = 8;
A = randi(5,[m n]);
Arot = flipud(A);
Arot = [ Arot; Arot(end,:) ];
Arot = [ Arot, Arot(:,end) ];
pcolor(Arot);figure(gcf);
for i = 1 : n
  for j = 1 : m
    text(i + .5 , j + .5 ,num2str(Arot(j,i)),'FontSize',18);
  end
end
```

Comment: +1 I never get why `pcolor` is used at all. `imagesc` looks much more natural to me :-)

Comment: @LuisMendo One of things that `pcolor` can do is to properly display images that are not on a rectilinear grid (you have to use `shading interp`, too). It's slow and a mem hog, but it can work for some scenarios.

Answer (score 4):

Using [`imagesc`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/imagesc.html) instead of `pcolor` solves the problem. It also brings some other benefits:

- Avoids the need for `flipud`;
- The coordinates of the `text` objects become integer values;
- Axes are automatically set to "matrix" mode, with the origin in the upper right corner.

Code:

```
m = 8;
n = 6;
A = randi(5,[m n]);
imagesc(A);
for ii = 1:n
    for jj = 1:m
        text(ii, jj, num2str(A(jj,ii)), 'FontSize', 18);
    end
end
```

For

```
A =
     4     5     4     2     4     4
     5     4     3     4     4     2
     5     4     1     1     1     3
     4     3     5     2     5     4
     1     2     2     2     5     3
     1     5     2     5     1     3
     4     3     1     3     3     1
     3     1     2     4     2     3
```

this produces

[image]