# How to plot with specific colors the values of a matrix in matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix, plot, colors, matlab-figure

I am working in matlab and I have a matrix which I would like to visualize it by giving a green-ish color to the lowest values per column/row and red-ish to the rest or different levels of red-ish depending on how close or far this values is from the lowest one and lastly print the values within. For example lets say that I have the following matrix:

```
0.0085 0.0244 0.0335 0.0312 0.0392 0.0392
0.0246 0.0078 0.0234 0.0281 0.0395 0.0395
0.0299 0.0295 0.0108 0.0224 0.0598 0.0598
0.0253 0.0317 0.0236 0.0123 0.0583 0.0583
0.0363 0.0337 0.0500 0.0497 0.0038 0.0583
```

what I want to achieve is something like this:

[image]

is there anyhow a way to achieve the above result?

I was checking on pcolor or imagesc functions but I couldn't get along with something. I found these links [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3942892/how-do-i-visualize-a-matrix-with-colors-and-values-displayed) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26705092/plot-a-matrix-values-as-colors) that they kind of try to do something similar but I couldn't get it to change it to my needs. Therefore, does anybody know if it is possible something like that to be done and how?

Thanks.

---

**Update:**

In case that I want to add also some titlebars on the top and on the side, look below:

[image]

Comment: It looks like you try to force MATLAB to be EXCEL...

Comment: Just wanted to save the time from transfering this from matlab to excel. Since I need only the visualization part and it can be done straight forward  in matlab why spend time one this. I think your answer will help other people as well. Well done, thanks again ;-).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a quick option:

```
A = [0.0085 0.0244 0.0335 0.0312 0.0392 0.0392
    0.0246 0.0078 0.0234 0.0281 0.0395 0.0395
    0.0299 0.0295 0.0108 0.0224 0.0598 0.0598
    0.0253 0.0317 0.0236 0.0123 0.0583 0.0583
    0.0363 0.0337 0.0500 0.0497 0.0038 0.0583];
back = [1 0 0];
headers = [0.5 0.5 0.5];
minima = [0 1 0];
map = [back ; headers; minima];
colormap(map)
[~,ind] = min(A);
B = zeros(size(A));
for k = 1:size(A,2)
    B(ind(k),k) = 1;
end
B = [ones(1,size(B,2))*0.5;B];
B = [ones(size(B,1),1)*0.5 B];
imagesc(B)
axis off
[y,x]=ndgrid((1:size(A,1)),(1:size(A,2)));
row_titles = num2str((1:size(A,1)).'); % could be any vector...
text(ones(size(A,1),1),2:size(A,1)+1,row_titles,'FontSize',16,'HorizontalAlignment','center',...
    'VerticalAlignment','middle','Color','w')
coloumn_titles = num2str((1:size(A,2)).'); % could be any vector...
text(2:size(A,2)+1,ones(size(A,2),1),coloumn_titles,'FontSize',16,'HorizontalAlignment','center',...
    'VerticalAlignment','middle','Color','w')
text(x(:)+1,y(:)+1,num2str(A(:)),'FontSize',16,'HorizontalAlignment','center',...
    'VerticalAlignment','middle')
```

which gives:

[image: minfig]

and you can change the `headers`, `back` and `minima` colors to fit your prefered style.

Comment: thanks for the answer it seems quite more efficient in regards to Rotem's answer for that reason you got the correct answer. However, what if I want also to add some titlebars, check my update in my initial post.

Comment: also I figured out that the for loop can be skipped with the following alternative code:

rows = 1:size(A,2);
linInd=sub2ind(size(A),ind,rows);
B(linInd) = 1;

and some transparency can be added with:

him = imagesc(B);
set(him,'AlphaData',0.5);

Comment: Correct, I just tried to keep the answer simple, and focus on the basic visualizition method.

Answer (score 2):

You can find the minimum on each column, and create a matrix that associates a colour with the corresponding index of the minimum.

This example creates a color for the minima of each column.

```
[~, idx] = min(A);
M = zeros(size(A));
for iCol = 1:size(A,2)
    M(idx(iCol), iCol) = 1;
end
imagesc(M);
```

Similarly, you can create a function to assign the desired colour to each value.
If you each to print the string of the values on, you can use the text function.

Comment: thanks @serigado your answer is on the same path as BMH's one ;-)

Comment: actually BMH's answer was taken from mine, implementing the colorbar and adding strings with the text function as I had said.

Comment: To be honest, I didn't see your answer when I wrote mine. Only after I posted it I saw you suggested something in the same direction. I decided to leave it because it give the full solution, which other parts of are also important (like how to use `text` correctly). Anyway, you got my upvote too ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can create it using `insertText`.

Use something like the following sample:

```
A = [0.0085 0.0244 0.0335 0.0312 0.0392 0.0392
     0.0246 0.0078 0.0234 0.0281 0.0395 0.0395
     0.0299 0.0295 0.0108 0.0224 0.0598 0.0598
     0.0253 0.0317 0.0236 0.0123 0.0583 0.0583
     0.0363 0.0337 0.0500 0.0497 0.0038 0.0583];

I = zeros(92, 348, 3, 'uint8');
I(:,:,1) = 255;I(:,:,2) = 199;I(:,:,3) = 206; %Background color

text_str = cell(length(A(:)), 1);
box_color = zeros(length(A(:)), 3);
text_color = zeros(length(A(:)), 3);
position = zeros(length(A(:)), 2);
for y = 0:size(A, 1)-1
    for x = 0:size(A,2)-1
        index = y*size(A,2) + x + 1;
        val = A(y+1, x+1);
        text_str{index} = [' ', num2str(val, '%0.4f'), ' '];
        position(index, 1) = x*58 + 1;
        position(index, 2) = y*18 + 1;
        if (val == min(A(:, x+1)))
            %Green
            box_color(index, :) = uint8([198, 239, 206]);
            text_color(index, :) = uint8([0, 100, 0]);
        else
            %Red
            box_color(index, :) = uint8([255, 199, 206]);
            text_color(index, :) = uint8([100, 0, 0]);
        end
    end
end

I = insertText(I, position, text_str, 'FontSize', 12, 'BoxColor', box_color, 'TextColor', text_color, 'BoxOpacity', 1);

figure;imshow(I);
```

Note: In newer version of Matlab (newer than I used), you can also select the font.

[image]

Comment: thank you for the answer. Though with your solution I think you can apply more customizations in regards to EBH's answer I think EBH's is a bit more simple to understand and efficient in lines of code as well. If I could mark your answer as correct I would do it but unfortunately I can't. You got my upvote though ;-). What about adding some titlebars?

Comment: EBH's answer is absolutlly better, he also got an upvote from me.