# Show all elements of a binary array in a pcolor plot of MATLAB (2D binary data)

Tags: matlab, plot, binary

Suppose that we have this array and `pcolor` function in MATLAB:

```
jj = [0,1,0;1,0,1;1,1,0];
pcolor(jj);
```

Plot:

[image]

I want show all elements of `jj` matrix in this `pcolor` plot so we should have a 3*3 plot. How can I do this in MATLAB?

Anyway, to show only row and column numbers in a plot not above vertical and horizontal scaling? Is there any other recommended suitable type of plots to show this type of data (2D binary data)?

Comment: Why not use `imshow` or `imagesc`?

Comment: Thank you for comment. Please add your answer for questions. I checked `imagesc`. It worked. What's your idea about two other questions?

Comment: I don't understand the question about row/column numbers. Can you show a diagram of what you mean?

Comment: I don't want this scaling in horizontal and vertical axes. I only want number of rows and columns. for instance I want only number 1 instead of 1 to 2 scaling (in middle).

Comment: + anyway two show lines between boxes in `imagesc` (such as above plot)?

Comment: Have a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39516274/how-to-plot-with-specific-colors-the-values-of-a-matrix-in-matlab/39521450#39521450) for another option to use `imagesc` to visualize your data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want all of the image data to be displayed with `pcolor`, you need to pad the input with an extra row and column prior to printing since underneath, `pcolor` is a `surf` object and the colors are assigned to the *vertices* not the *faces*.

```
jj = [0,1,0;1,0,1;1,1,0];

% Add an extra column
jj(:,end+1) = 0;

% Add an extra row
jj(end+1,:) = 0;

p = pcolor(jj);
```

Now if you want only the integer labels on the axes, you can tweak them using the `XTick`/`Ytick` and `XTickLabel`/`YTickLabel` properties of the `axes` to draw the proper values for each element

```
xlims = get(gca, 'XLim');
ylims = get(gca, 'YLim');

% Must offset ticks by 0.5 to center them
xticks = (xlims(1) + 0.5):(xlims(2) - 0.5);
yticks = (ylims(1) + 0.5):(ylims(2) - 0.5);

xticklabels = arrayfun(@num2str, 1:numel(xticks), 'UniformOutput', 0);
yticklabels = arrayfun(@num2str, 1:numel(yticks), 'UniformOutput', 0);

set(gca, 'xtick', xticks, 'ytick', yticks, ...
         'xticklabel', xticklabels, 'yticklabel', yticklabels)
```

If you don't need the black edges, you can accomplish the same 2D plot by just using `imagesc`

```
imagesc(jj);

xlims = get(gca, 'xlim');
ylims = get(gca, 'ylim');

set(gca, 'xtick', xlims(1):xlims(2), 'ytick', ylims(1):ylims(2))
```