# Convert char output into image in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

Is there a way to convert matlab text output into an image file?

For example, if I have an output like this:

```
17    24     1     8    15
23     5     7    14    16
 4     6    13    20    22
10    12    19    21     3
11    18    25     2     9
```

Can I convert this into an image? Like taking a screen snapshot
of this matrix area?

Thanks.

note:  the result need to be aligned like the text output.
i know how to align using different font. i was looking for an
alternative way of aligning numbers. i was only asking for the possibility
of taking a snap shot effect.

Comment: i don't understand the negative check. is it because it is too simple?. if it is, at  least provide an answer before checking negative.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [msgbox](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/msgbox.html) function to display the matrix in a `figure`; the matrix has to be converted to string with the functino [num2str](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/num2str.html), then you have to:

- remove the *OK* button:

  - use the [findobj](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/findobj.html) function to get the `handle` of the pushbutton
  - delete it with the [delete](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/delete.html) function
- set the message box figure `HandleVisibility` to `on` (by default it is set to `callback`
- use the function `print` to print the message box figure as an image

This is the implementation:

```
% Create the message box
x=msgbox(num2str(a),'Dump of matrix a')
% Set the message box figure HandleVisibility to on
x.HandleVisibility='on'
% Find the handle of the OK pushbutton
hp=findobj(x,'style','pushbutton')
% Delete the OK pushbutton
delete(hp)
% Print the figure
print -djpeg99 image_of_a_matrix
```

**Edit to answer the commenrt about the *alignment* of the text**

In the textbox represents the numbers are represented as a string; even if in the generation of the string you properly align the number, the representation of the string depends on the font selected.

If you use [Monospaced font](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monospaced_font) such as, for example, Courier, Courier New, Lucida Console you can obtain the dsesired alignment.

At the contrary, if you use *proportional fonts* you will lose the alignment since different characters occupies different amount of horizontal space.

With respect to the above proposed code, you can set the a *Monospaced font* (e. g. *Courier*) this way:

```
% Create the message box
x=msgbox(num2str(a),'Dump of matrix a')
% Set the message box figure HandleVisibility to on
x.HandleVisibility='on'
% Find the handle of the OK pushbutton
hp=findobj(x,'style','pushbutton')
% Delete the OK pushbutton
delete(hp)
% Get the handle of the text item
txt_h=x.Children.Children
% Change the text font
txt_h.FontName='Courier'
txt_h.FontWeight='bold'
% Print the figure
print -djpeg99 image_of_a_matrix_1
```

This is the image with **Proportional font**:

[image]

This is the image with **Monospaced font**:

[image]

Hope this helps,

Qapla'

Comment: thanks. but i was looking for an aligned result. numbers in your result are not aligned.

Comment: I've updated the answer: the problem of the _alignement_ is due to the type of font. You can achieve it by using_Monospaced_ fonts such as _Courier_.

Comment: thank you very much. i am looking for alternative approach to get the aligned result, which is an image capture.  but still, appreciate it.

Comment: OK, I'm sorry not to have been of help, anyway, [you could try this](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/24323-screencapture-get-a-screen-capture-of-a-figure-frame-or-component)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [insertText](https://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/ref/inserttext.html) function, to insert text into an image.

Here is my code sample:

```
A = [17    24     1     8    15
     23     5     7    14    16
      4     6    13    20    22
     10    12    19    21     3
     11    18    25     2     9];

[n_rows, n_cols] = size(A);

%Set background color to [240, 240, 240] (light gray).
I = zeros(n_rows*24+12, n_cols*10*5+8, 3, 'uint8') + 240; %Background color

text_str = cell(n_rows, 1); 
box_color = zeros(n_rows, 3) + 240; %Set box color to same as background color
text_color = repmat([125, 39, 39], n_rows, 1); %Set text color to brown.

%Fill rows of A into cell array text_str
for i = 1:n_rows
    text_str{i} = sprintf('%5d', A(i, :));
end

%Set position of each of the rows.
pos_x = zeros(1, n_rows) + 4;
pos_y = (0:n_rows-1)*24 + 6;
position = [pos_x', pos_y'];

%Insert text into image I.
I = insertText(I, position, text_str, 'FontSize', 14, 'BoxColor', box_color, 'TextColor', text_color,...
               'Font', 'Courier New Bold', 'BoxOpacity', 1);

figure;imshow(I);
```

Result:
[image]

---

**Aligned text with different font:**

Applying my solution for aligning text with no fixed width, requires different coordinate for each number (total of 25 coordinated and 25 strings).

The following solution uses Arial font:

```
A = [17    24     1     8    15
     23     5     7    14    16
      4     6    13    20    22
     10    12    19    21     3
     11    18    25     2     9];

[n_rows, n_cols] = size(A);
n_elms = numel(A);

%Set background color to [240, 240, 240] (light gray).
I = zeros(n_rows*24+12, n_cols*10*5+8, 3, 'uint8') + 240; %Background color

text_str = cell(n_elms, 1);
box_color = zeros(n_elms, 3) + 240; %Set box color to same as background color
text_color = repmat([125, 39, 39], n_elms, 1); %Set text color to brown.

%Fill rows and columns of A into cell array text_str
counter = 1;
for y = 1:n_rows
    for x = 1:n_cols
        text_str{counter} = sprintf('%5d', A(y, x));
        counter = counter + 1;
    end
end

%Set position of each of the rows and columns.
[pos_x, pos_y] = ndgrid(0:n_cols-1, 0:n_rows-1);
pos_x = pos_x(:)*10*5 + 4;
pos_y = pos_y(:)*24 + 6;
position = [pos_x, pos_y];

%Insert text into image I.
I = insertText(I, position, text_str, 'FontSize', 14, 'BoxColor', box_color, 'TextColor', text_color,...
               'Font', 'Arial Bold', 'AnchorPoint','RightTop', 'BoxOpacity', 1);

figure;imshow(I);
```

Result:
[image]

Comment: thanks.but  i was looking for an aligned result. the reason your result is aligned, is because your font is courier. if you change to another font, will it still be aligned? i was looking for an alternative way to using aligned font.

Comment: Actually, I had a working solution without monospaced font, I just tried to make it more simple. Here is my previous post: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39516274/how-to-plot-with-specific-colors-the-values-of-a-matrix-in-matlab](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39516274/how-to-plot-with-specific-colors-the-values-of-a-matrix-in-matlab)